# Turn off default rotate animation in iOS

Tags: iphone, ios, cocoa-touch, animation, uikit

When I rotate my iDevice form portrait to landscape, the screen rotates fine, but I'm seeing black borders moving with it, so it looks more 'real'. I find it embarrassing to see in iOS 7 and many apps have thrashed this behaviour (like Instagram).

What I want to do is hide those black borders that look totally unnecessary when rotating a device. How do I disable this standard animation?

Comment: While in normal state its work fine?

Comment: @Ganapathy What I described is the *normal state* :)

Comment: is it possible to share your screen (Hide the official content)

Comment: @Ganapathy don't bother, the problem is solved)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the parent view controller viewdidload method add this:

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(didRotate:) name:@"UIDeviceOrientationDidChangeNotification" object:nil];
```

Then add this method

```
- (void) didRotate:(NSNotification *)notification {     

    UIDeviceOrientation orientation = [[UIDevice currentDevice] orientation];
    if (UIInterfaceOrientationIsLandscape(orientation) && !self.modalViewController) {
        [self presentModalViewController:carouselView animated:YES];
        [Globals sharedGlobals].startedAtLandscape = YES;
    }

    if (UIInterfaceOrientationIsPortrait(orientation) && self.modalViewController) {
    [self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];    
    [Globals sharedGlobals].startedAtLandscape = NO;
    }
}
```

Then to prevent animation:

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{
    if(UIInterfaceOrientationIsLandscape(interfaceOrientation)) {
        return NO;
    }
    return YES;
}
```

Comment: Although your code example is very subjective, I have managed to do the trick first committing animations, then using `[UIView setAnimationsEnabled:NO];` and then setting it to `yes` after the `duration` time interval. Works like charm.

Answer (score 1):

I found the best solution is turn animation off before rotation, and turn it back after rotation.

```
- (void)willRotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)toInterfaceOrientation
                                duration:(NSTimeInterval)duration
{
    ...
    [UIView setAnimationsEnabled:NO];
}

- (void) didRotateFromInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)fromInterfaceOrientation
{
    ...
    [UIView setAnimationsEnabled:YES];
}
```